About inequality related with upper gradients
Suppose we have a Riemannian manifold $M$. At $p \in M$ we pick exponential coordinates so that $\exp_p : B(0,\epsilon) \subset T_pM \rightarrow B(p,\epsilon) \subset M$ is a diffeomorphism. Let $q \in B(p,\epsilon)$. Let $c \in \Omega_{p,q}$, the set of segments (locally minimizing geodesics) joining $p$ to $q$.
Suppose $f : M \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is smooth. Then $f \circ c$ is smooth so that by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have $$|f(q)-f(p)| = |f(c(1))-f(c(0))| =\int_0^1|\dot{f \circ c}(t)|dt = \int_0^1|\langle \nabla f,\dot{c}\rangle dt \leq C\int_0^1|\nabla f|dt,$$where $|\dot{c}| \equiv C$.
Now, there's a proof that I am seeing that uses $$|f(q)-f(p)| \leq \int_0^1d(p,q)|\nabla f(c_{p,q}(t))|dt.$$There's a remark saying that this inequality in fact holds for any measurable function $f$ with a function $G$ in place of $|\nabla f|$ and such $G$ is called an upper gradient.
I am looking for a proof of this, in particular, if anyone knows the proof for my specific case of a Riemannian manifold would be better.
Edit: For my case, I believe this has to do with the reparametrization of the curve $c$ by making it $|\dot{c}| = |pq| = d(p,q)$ but I am not sure how to properly justify it.
Thanks in advance.
